# Texto está saindo com espaços no console e não está dando match no Regex

Tags: java, sql

Estou criando um código para validar inserts de SQL que está em um TXT, mas o match do regex nunca bate e percebi que no console o texto sai espaçado assim:

"I N S E R T    I N T O    T A B L E    V A L U E S    "
= [Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSXFs.png)

E até se eu fazer um contains "INSERT" sempre da false

Código atual:

```
    private static boolean isInsertStatement(String line) {
        int commas = commaCounter(line);
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(line.contains("INSERT"));
        if (commas == 0) { return true; }
        String valuesPattern = "[^,]*";
        for (int i = 0; i < commas; i++) {
            valuesPattern += ", [^,]*";
        }

                
        String insertPattern = "INSERT INTO [^,]* VALUES (" + valuesPattern + ");";
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(insertPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        
        //System.out.println(insertPattern);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Alguém sabe dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Os comentários se estenderam bastante e foram convertidos em [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146022/discussion-on-question-by-victor-l-bueno-texto-esta-saindo-com-espacos-no-conso), utilizem o link para prosseguir.

Comment: Sobre a pergunta, para fins de site seria importante [edit] e converter num [mcve]. A [help] pode ajudar bastante no entendimento do site, e de que tipo de pergunta é esperado aqui. Ou, para ajuda individual, os colegas podem usar o link do chat fornecido no comentário anterior.